# How can I sync the rotation of some images with their rotation metadata on Windows without loading a full graphics app?

Tags: images, photos, metadata, pictures

I've recently noticed that some of my photos I've taken with my point-and-shoot camera have mismatched actual rotation vs rotation metadata.

I'm not sure if this is because my Canon IXUS is dying or due to some other reason. But all photos I've taken in recent weeks with the camera held sideways or upside down have this out-of-sync metadata.

This makes a difference with some apps or sites trusting the metadata over the image and some doing the opposite. (I've noticed this since uploading photos to Google Deep Dream results in a different orientation to what I see on my computer.)

So I'm wondering how I can fix these either from the commandline or GUI but without having to load a big graphics app like GIMP.